# How to return data in JSON format in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to return some data in JSON format, I created serializers.py

```
class LocationSerializers(serializers.EmbeddedDocumentSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = location
    fields = '__all__'

class ProductsSerializers(serializers.DocumentSerializer):
  location = LocationSerializers(many=True)
  class Meta:
    model = products
    fields = ('picture', 'name', 'email', 'city', 'location')
```

Models.py

```
class location(EmbeddedDocument):
  type = fields.StringField()
  coordinates = fields.ListField(FloatField())

class products(Document):
  picture = fields.StringField()
  name = fields.StringField()
  email = fields.StringField()
  city = fields.StringField()
  location = fields.EmbeddedDocumentField('location')
```

and views.py

```
def get(self, request):
    prd = products.objects.all()
    data = ProductsSerializers(prd,many=True)
    return Response(data.data)
```

When i return one product it work but wehn i want to return all didn't work
I don't understand error

```
The fields "{'_ref'}" do not exist on the document "location"
```

Comment: It looks like you're using DRF? You might want to add the relevant tag. Also, `EmbeddedDocumentField` seems to be for Mongo? You might have to write some custom serialization logic to handle that type of field.

Comment: @Blurp i write my own serializers.py look in top

Comment: Write, but I said "custom serialization logic", meaning that you might have to do something special to handle that field type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find solution just i change EmbeddedDocumentSerializer to EmbeddedDocumentSerializer

```
class location(EmbeddedDocument):
```

to

```
class Location(DynamicDocument):
```

> Using DynamicDocuments, you can save any extra attributes without defining excplicitly on the model